# Nginx conditional proxy pass configuration

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I have 2 different ( Node & Angular ) applications running under a domain. I am trying to configure nginx in way to serve like, whenever anyone access "domain.com" it should serve the node app running on port 4200 and if someone access "domain.com/admin" it should serve the contents from Angular app. Below is my nginx configuration.

```
 server {
    listen   80;
    listen   [::]:80;

    server_name domain.com

}


server {
    listen   443 default_server ssl;
    ssl on;
    server_name domain.com;
    root /home/domain/public_html/angular/dist;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

 
    location / {
                        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4200;
                        proxy_http_version 1.1;
                        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                        proxy_set_header Host $host;
                        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                        proxy_redirect off;
    }
     location /admin {
         try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
    }
```

The problem I am facing now is all the requests including `/admin` is getting proxy passed. Is there any way I can restrict the `/admin` requests to not get proxy passed? Below is the nginx log.

```
connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: domain.com, request: "GET /admin HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4200/admin", host: "domain.com"
```

Can someone please shed some light to get this resolved?

Comment: What files are in the `/home/domain/public_html/angular/dist` folder?

Comment: That folder contains the Angular app build output, like index.html, assets, vendor etc.

Comment: `Connection refused` means your node app is not running or not listening on port 4200.

Comment: Hi Michael, what I want is when we access domain.com/admin it should serve the index.html without that port 4200.